# Edittext input type password, not hiding text after clear focus android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am using a view to enter user's four digit PIN. the UI consists of 4 edittext each having maxLength set to 1. On entering value to edit text1, focus is then shifted to the second edittext and so on. each Edittext input type is : numberPassword.

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/ed_1"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="numberPassword"
            android:maxLength="1" />
```

In java, to shift the focus, we have applied following text watcher to each of the edittext:

```
ed1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.toString().length() == 1) {
                ed1.clearFocus();
                ed2.requestFocus();
                ed2.setCursorVisible(true);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Problem is, value of edittext are not changing to *, it shows the real input number (not changing to password). Only 1st and last are changing to *, where as center two that means edittext 2 and edittext 3 are still have visible passwords.

Right now: We have 4 input Edittexts

desired output should be: **| * | * | * | * |**

When we fill the values, and switches the focus, by using java code specified, they get change to: (input value: 1234): **| * | 2 | 3 | * |**

If we focus back on either of the center edit texts, then value changes to password. Is it because of removing focus, and the transformation time required to change a field to password takes more time? Is there any method with which we can forcefully change the value to password.

Comment: Because you are not using this property for that two edit text. Set this property android:inputType="textPassword" and its done sir

Comment: I wish it would have been so easy. Every edittext is exact replicate of the one specified in the question. Each one has  android:inputType="numberPassword"

Comment: Try putting the code in a Runnable, and post it, does it help?

Comment: you can use **Handler** for delay so that it will change text. [Check my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46232350/edittext-input-type-password-not-hiding-text-after-clear-focus-android/#answer-46233151)

Comment: Have you find proper solution for this? I am also facing same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running the following code for the previous text after the transitions

```
yourEditText.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
```

it's a difficult method but

```
String e1,e2,e3,e4; 
@Override 
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) { 
if (s.toString().length() == 1 && !ed1.getText().toString().equals("*")) { 
e1=ed1.getText(); 
ed1.setText("*"); 
ed2.requestFocus(); 
ed2.setCursorVisible(true); } }
```

you can use this method

Comment: ed1.setText("*");  in onTextChanged will again invoke onTextChanged with condition true, and will go in an infinite loop.. hence causing ANR.

Comment: update! 
You can prevent infinite loop by adding control

Comment: yes, it works! Thanks. but what do you think would be the cause of this problem?

Comment: i dont know, time may be a problem, but why just 2 and 3, i no idea.

Comment: @user3099103 This does not solve the issue, it just bypasses it. It also introduces some bugs. What happens when a user erases the text? What does he do if his password is an "asterisk"? Reinventing the wheel is always risky

Comment: The password consists only of numbers, and you are right in deleting For this  **if(ed1.getText()!=null) ed1.setText("*");** you need to add.

Comment: Delete does not enter query because lenght() = 0

Answer (score 1):

Because you set the maxLength to 1, so it will get single character only. Also you written code for clearFocus in the onTextChanged, so it will set focus to the next EditText. You have to change as like below in your xml.

```
<EditText
  android:id="@+id/ed_1"
  android:layout_width="20dp"
  android:layout_height="20dp"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:inputType="numberPassword"
  android:maxLength="4" />
```

Also remove the clearFocus in your onTextChanged().

Comment: The UI cannot be achieved by using single edittext with max length to 4. We need 4 edittexts, each having max length to 1.  And focus should be switched to the next edittext, after filling one.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like ***TextWatcher*** need *some time to chenge it to password type*,
so i came up to this solution with using **Handler** and it works fine. Try below code

```
ed1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (s.toString().length() == 1) {

            // use Handler for 1 second delay so that it will change text
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ed2.requestFocus();
                }
            },1000);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `ed1.clearFocus();` from your code. Do not force the edittext to loose his focus, just tell the other edittext to regain the focus `ed2.requestFocus();` . The previous edittext automatically remove its focus as soon as next edittext gain the focus. It will first transform the value then leave its focus.

Answer (score 0):

Just move your code from onTextChanged to afterTextChanged, and you don´t need clearFocus, just requestFocus.

This way you give time to obfuscate the number before change focus.